# Comparison gives different results in Coffeescript/Javascript and Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, coffeescript

Example:

```
[42] == [42]
```

The result of the comparison gives different results:

```
CS/JS: false
Ruby:  true
```

On the other hand:

```
42 == 42
```

gives the result:

```
CS/JS: true
Ruby:  true
```

What is the reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answerers have done a good job of explaining the JavaScript/CoffeeScript equality semantics. (CoffeeScript's `==` compiles to JavaScript's stricter `===`, but that makes no difference in this case.)

The Ruby case is more complex: Everything in Ruby is an object, and so every object has a `==` method which, in principle, could do anything. In the case of arrays, it looks at the other array, checks if it has the same length, and then checks if `x == y` for each `x` in itself and `y` in the other array.

If you want to emulate the Ruby behavior, it's quite simple to write a function to do so:

```
deepEquals = (arr1, arr2) ->
  return false unless arr1.length is arr2.length
  for i in [0...arr1.length]
    if arr1[i] instanceof Array and arr2[i] instanceof Array
      return false unless deepEquals(arr1[i], arr2[i])
    else
      return false if arr1[i] isnt arr2[i] 
  true
```

Answer (score 2):

For the Javascript case the comparisons are fundamentally different.

Each `[42]` is a new array and arrays don't compare structurally they simply check to see if they are the same object.  So

```
[42] == [42]; // false. Different objects
var x = [42];
var y = [42];
x == y;       // false. Same check as [42] == [42]
x == x;       // true.  Same object
```

The literal 42 is a primitive type and compares by value.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, arrays are compared by reference, not by value.  `[42]` and `[42]` are different entities (albeit clones of one another) and therefore not equal.

The fact that 42 is the answer to everything is, unfortunately, not relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript

```
[42] == [42]
```

says "Are these two arrays the same object?" (no they're not), which is not the same as asking "Do these two arrays contain the same elements?"

On the other hand:

```
42 == 42
```

"Are these two number primitives equal comparing by value?"

(Note: this is an oversimplification of what JavaScript is doing because the `==` operator will attempt to convert both operands to the same type; contrast with the `===` operator.)